# Como inverter um vetor em C?

Tags: c, array, vector

Criei uma funcao para inverter vetores no entanto quando rodo o programa nao me aparece nada.
Este e o meu codigo para já:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define DIMV 30


int lerIntPositivo(){
    int numero;
    do{
        printf("Numeros=");
        scanf("%d", &numero);
    }while(numero<0);
    return numero;
}

void preencherVetor(int vetor[], int nElementos){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<nElementos;i++)
    vetor[i]=lerIntPositivo();
}
void listarVetor(int vetor[],int nElementos){
int i;
for (i=0;i<nElementos;i++)
    printf("%d\n",vetor[i]);

}
void inverter(int vetor[],int nElementos){
    int i;
    int vi[];
    for(i=0;i<nElementos;i++){
        vi[i]=vetor[nElementos-(1+i)];
        i++;

    }
return vi;
}
int main(){

int rotacoes[DIMV];
preencherVetor(rotacoes,5);
listarVetor(rotacoes,5);
printf(inverter(rotacoes,5));
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `printf(inverter(rotacoes,5));` não vai imprimir nada, a função `void inverter` é void, logo não retorna nada para imprimir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como mencionado pelo @RicardoPontual no comentário, sua função é `void`, então realmente não deve retornar valor algum. Para retornar um vetor em C, é necessário **retornar um ponteiro para uma região de memória alocada grande o suficiente para guardar a quantidade de itens que deseja**:

```
int* inverter(int vetor[], int nElementos);
```

Com uma implementação parecida com isso:

```
int* inverter(int vetor[], int nElementos) {
    int i;
    int* vi = malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
    
    for(i = 0; i < nElementos; i++) {
        vi[i] = vetor[nElementos - (1+i)];
    }
    
    return vi;
}
```

Ao receber o valor do vetor, você pode iterar pelos itens ao incrementar o valor de memória previamente alocado e liberá-lo ao final:

```
int rotacoes[DIMV];
preencherVetor(rotacoes,5);
listarVetor(rotacoes,5);

int* vetor = inverter(rotacoes,5);

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    printf("%i\n", *(vetor+i));
}

free(vetor);

return 0;
```

O resultado seria:

```
Numeros=1
Numeros=2
Numeros=3
Numeros=4
Numeros=5
5
4
3
2
1
```